# Android EditText OnClickListener Issue

Tags: android

I have sales application. When the user click on EditText the popup calculator want to display. In my case when user double click on `EditText onClickLister` only it display the popup calculator.

This is myEditText

```
    final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
            txtQty.setHeight(1);
            if(productList.get(i).getQty() != 0.00){
                txtQty.setText(Double.toString(productList.get(i).getQty()));
            }
            txtQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,42));
            txtQty.setTextSize(9);
            txtQty.setId(i);
            txtQty.setHint("0");
            txtQty.setClickable(true);
            txtQty.setSelected(true);
            txtQty.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
            txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            tr.addView(txtQty);
```

This is my code:

```
   txtQty.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String productCode= txtCode.getText().toString();
                    double price = getProductPrice(productCode).getPrice();
                    txtPrice.setText(""+price);

                    if(invPriceEdit.equals("3")){ 
                        if(editPrice.getText().toString().equals("") || editPrice.getText().toString().equals("0.00") || editPrice.getText().toString().equals("0") || editPrice.getText().toString().equals("0.0")){
                            txtPrice.setText(""+ price);
                            editPrice.setText("" +price);
                        }else{
                            String ePrice = editPrice.getText().toString();
                            editPrice.setText("" +ePrice);
                        }
                    }


                        keyAmount = new StringBuffer();
                        if(keyAmount.length() > 0){
                            keyAmount.delete(0, keyAmount.length());
                        }

                        int[] origin = new int[2];
                        v.getLocationOnScreen(origin);
                        final int xVal = origin[0];
                        final int yVal = origin[1] ;

                        dialog = new Dialog(SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent());
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                        View vLoad = LayoutInflater.from(SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.key_pad, null);
                        dialog.setContentView(vLoad);
                        android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams lp= dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();  

                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);  
                        lp.x = xVal;
                        lp.y = yVal;
                        lp.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        lp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
                        lp.dimAmount = 0;            
                        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                        dialog.setCancelable(false);
                        keyamDisplay  = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.keyamDisplay);

                        Button  txtone = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtone);
                        txtone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("1");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());

                           }
                        });

                        Button  txttwo = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txttwo);
                        txttwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("2");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());

                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtthree = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtthree);
                        txtthree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("3");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtfour = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtfour);
                        txtfour.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("4");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtfive = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtfive);
                        txtfive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("5");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtsix = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtsix);
                        txtsix.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("6");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                         });

                        Button  txtseven = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtseven);
                        txtseven.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("7");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txteight = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txteight);
                        txteight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("8");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtnine = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtnine);
                        txtnine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("9");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtZero = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtZero);
                        txtZero.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                              keyAmount.append("0");
                              keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        Button  txtdot = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtdot);
                        txtdot.setEnabled(false);
                        txtdot.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                  keyAmount.append(".");
                                  keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                               }
                        });

                        Button  diaDelete = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.diaDelete);
                        diaDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                             if(keyAmount.length() > 0){
                                keyAmount.delete(keyAmount.length()-1, keyAmount.length());
                            }
                                keyamDisplay.setText("" + keyAmount.toString());
                           }
                        });

                        ImageButton imageSmileExit = (ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageSmileExit);
                        imageSmileExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                        Button  txtDialogOK = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtDialogOK);
                        txtDialogOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(View v) {
                               dialog.dismiss();
                         }

                      });
                    dialog.show();
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                }
                }
```

This is an issue for sale Rep. They want to double click on each and every product clcik.

I want to display popup calculator when the user select the textEditor . (Don't want double click).

This is my  Code:

```
       final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
            txtQty.setHeight(1);
            if(productList.get(i).getQty() != 0.00){
                txtQty.setText(Double.toString(productList.get(i).getQty()));
            }
            txtQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,42));
            txtQty.setTextSize(9);
            txtQty.setId(i);
            txtQty.setHint("0");
            txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            tr.addView(txtQty);
```

Problem is:

`TableLayout contain list of product info
when the user click on Qty it popup calculator
after enter the value, it will clearFocus on  that row EditText qty & It go to first Row EditText'

this is the picture of my screen

[image: picture of my screen]

Comment: where is the picture? can you please rewrite your problem again, some parts are not very clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done using setOnTouchListener

```
    disValEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { } });
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I am only wondering why we should not use ACTION_DOWN in order to handle clicks on the EditText. Is there a certain reason for using ACTION_UP instead?

Answer (score 6):

why are you adding `onClickEvent` on your EditText,

For EditText it makes sense to use `onFocusChangeListener()` which will fire up the dialog as soon as edittext gets focus. In `onFocusChangeListener()` you can check if the `EditText` is *getting focus or loosing focus*.

Comment: Before I wrote my code on `onFocusChangeListener()` . Problem was when user by mistake enter 3 ,so he want to change to 5 that time we can't call it again in same `EditText`

Comment: well you can make sure when you close your dialog box you remove focus from EditText(), that way clicking it agin will cause dialog to re-appear

Comment: How to remove focus from EditText().I tried when when popup window dismiss called this `txtQty.setFocusable(false);` .But not working

Comment: another way to think about it is when your dialog box opens, your EditText looses focus as dialog box gains focus. I am not sure that if by exiting the dialog box the EditText will automatically gain the focus.

Comment: @Frankenstein yes. this is ok.Problem is: `TableLayout contain list of product binfo
when the user click on Qty it popup calculator
after enter the value, it will set & clear that row EditText qty
when i clear that particular row focus it go tthat focus to first row EditText`

Answer (score 2):

If its like you never want to let user input it's value through the KeyBoard and want the user to input value from dialog.

Then Why to use `EditText`, You can Have a `TextView` give it a proper background and text font.

And then write onClickListener for that `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this in your code (in click event):

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

And what also could be a problem, is that maybe somewhere in your XML file,
That it says: `<requestFocus />`.
delete this

Comment: I created EditText dynamically. I tried this also.Not working

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
txtQty.setEditable(false);
txtQty.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you intend to "Do sth" when user "double clicks" the EditText.

Not sure if it is the best solution, 
Here a sample to do so.
Mimic the "double clicks" by a 500ms countdown.

```
private EditText ed1;
private CountDownTimer timer;
private Boolean isWaiting = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    timer = new CountDownTimer(500, 500) {


        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            isWaiting = false;

        }
    };

    ed1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(isWaiting) {
                isWaiting = false;
                timer.cancel();
                // TODO: Pop Up Calculator
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                isWaiting = true;
                timer.start();
            }

        }
    });
  }
```